# How to compare two classifications' classes' size?

Tags: classification, chi-squared-test, p-value, sample-size

I want to know if, between two classifications, one provides more homogeneous classes size than the other.

I devised to use the chi square test (classes' size are far more than the rule of thumb of 5 or 10 frequencies), to compare each classification to the most homogeneous classification.

In example, if I have two classifications such as:

```
      1     2     3     4     5
A    31    33    45    25    56
B    29    30    41    30    60
```

Over 190 items classified,
I compared them (using chi square test) with

```
      1     2     3     4     5
H    38    38    38    38    38
```

Now I have two pvalues. May I assume that, if A's pvalue is greater than B's pvalue, A's classes are more homogeneous than B's, with respect to size?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. (This is an unusual use of the chi-square test, but I think your approach works for your purpose.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach would be to compare the chi-square tests' confidence intervals of A and B. If the confidence intervals (for example, 95% confidence intervals) do not overlap, you can conclude that you are 95% confident that A's classes are more homogeneous than B's classes. Otherwise, you do not have evidence to conclude that either groups' classes are more/less homogeneous than the other group's. I hope this helps!

Comment: You are right.. Thanks. Do you know how to achieve it in Python or R?

Comment: Your terminology at the linked StackOverflow question was a little bit off, making the question confusing. If you want the confidence intervals of the *Pearson X^2 ("chi-square") statistic* for a given table, you might (???) be able to do this by Poisson-resampling the values in the table ...